# Why is Cout only being accounted for during addition and not subtraction in my adder/subtractor (Verilog)

Tags: verilog, alu

Here is my code:

```
module Adder_8b_df (A, B, opcode, S, Cout);
input [7:0] A, B;
input [3:0] opcode;
output [7:0] S;
output Cout;

wire [8:0] tmp;  

  assign tmp = (opcode[0] == 0) ? (A + B) : (A + (~B + 8'b1)); 
  assign S = tmp [7:0];  
  assign Cout  = tmp [8]; 

endmodule
```

Addition is performed when the first bit of the opcode is a 0, otherwise subtraction through two's complement is performed. Looking at the waveform, both operations perform correctly. However there is only a carry out (Cout) when addition is performed.

For instance when trying to subtract 0110_0011 from 1100_0110. The operation should be 1100_0110 + 1001_1101 which results in an overflow. The waveform still shows the correct answer: 0110_0011. But Cout is low not high. Any ideas why this is the case?

Edit: 
[image: Waveform shot]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because "~B" is extended to 9 bits (like tmp) and then it is overflows to bit 10 which you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved the problem:

```
module Adder_8b_df (A, B, opcode, S, Cout);
input [7:0] A, B;
input [3:0] opcode;
output [7:0] S;
output Cout;

wire [8:0] tmp;
wire [8:0] twos_comp;

  assign twos_comp = (opcode[0] == 1) ? (~B + 8'b1) : 0;
  assign tmp = (opcode[0] == 0) ? (A + B) : (A + (twos_comp [7:0]));
  assign S = tmp [7:0];
  or(Cout, twos_comp[8], tmp[8]);

endmodule
```